# Oracle Substring a column for last index of character

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do substring in Oracle using last index of a character '_'.

Not able to get it rite. Please see the query which does a substring of second occurrence of "-". But it does not work if the string only has one occurrence of "-".

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR('TEMP_ABC', 0, INSTR('TEMP_ABC', '_',1,2)-1), 'TEMP_ABC') 
    FROM DUAL

Result  - TEMP_ABC  
Expected Result - TEMP

SELECT NVL(SUBSTR('TEMP_ABC_XYZ', 0, INSTR('TEMP_ABC_XYZ', '_',1,2)-1), 'TEMP_ABC_XYZ') 
    FROM DUAL

Result - TEMP_ABC
Expected Result - TEMP_ABC
```

Any clue on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: And the statement of your requirement is..... ???

Comment: @mathguy -  For input  TEMP_ABC_XYZ  the output should be TEMP_ABC and for input TEMP_ABC the output should be TEMP

Comment: So - the output must be the input, minus the LAST underscore and everything that follows it? Also, don't forget to state what the desired output if there is NO underscore at all (or else, state that ALL inputs will have AT LEAST one underscore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In instr function, if you use -1 at the last parameter, it means last occurrence of the char string.

```
instr(string, '_', -1) = last occurrence of _
```

Thus:

```
select substr('TEMP_ABC',1,instr('TEMP_ABC','_',-1)-1)
from dual;

Result: TEMP

select substr('TEMP_ABC_XYZ',1,instr('TEMP_ABC_XYZ','_',-1)-1)
from dual;

Result: TEMP_ABC
```